# struct node in queue structure in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures

suppose I got a node like this:

```
struct node{
  int a;
  int b;
}
```

Now I want to make a queue structure in cpp.  If the data type was int then we could do that easily in this way:

```
queue<int> a;
```

And we could also push or pop elements like this: a. push_back(12) or a. pop(12)

But in the earlier case when out data type is user defined how can we make such a queue and push or pop elemeqnts from it?

Comment: I don't get what your problem is. You can well use `std::queue<node>` as you like. (Didn't dv BTW)

Comment: Exactly the same way, replace `int` with `node`. Have you even tried it?

Comment: How to push element there. Suppose I want to push 11, 12  for the first node.

Comment: You should create an object of `node` and then push it.

Comment: @AmirKhasru Something like `a.push_back(node{11,12})` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

struct s1{
    int a;
    string b;
};

class Foo{
    public:
    int a;
    string b;
};

int main()
{
  queue<Foo> q;
  Foo obj;
  obj.a=2;
  obj.b="Object";
  q.push(obj);
  Foo p=q.back();

  cout<<p.a<<endl;
  cout<<p.b<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is *absolutely no problem* in holding non-PODs like `struct` or `class` inside container like queue.

```
struct s1{
    int a;
    string b;
};
class Foo{
    int a;
    string b;
};
int main() {
    queue<int> qi;
    queue<s1> qs;
    queue<Foo> qfoo;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice.  It was awesome. But how to push such class or struct node there?

Comment: Basically you use containers to hold multiple instances of class or struct. So create instance and push them in. Then you can sort them, delete them, add more and do whatever you wish.

Comment: @SauravSahu Show them how to do actually. Feel free to take that from my comment.

Comment: suppose I got a queue like this: queue<node>a.  Now I want to push there 11 and 12. Then how can I push them?  Push_back(11, 12)?  This way?

Comment: @AmirKhasru Read my comment.

Comment: `struct node` **is** a POD type. But it's true that non-PODs can also be stored in a queue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
struct node{
    int a;
    int b;
};

std::queue<node> q;
```

you can use `push` as follows:

```
q.push({ 11, 12 });
```

this adds a `node` with a = 11 and b = 12.

<sup>This works as long as copy-list-initialization is possible, as it is in this case. Otherwise you would have to use `q.push(node{ 11, 12 });`</sup>

Comment: Supposed the constructor wasn't declared [`explicit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What constructor?

Comment: @DeiDei One imaginary given. I'm just trying to explore the whole space of possibilities.

Answer (score -4):

Use queue  a; make objects of node type and use functions a.push_back()
a.pop_front() to push and pop respectively.Also don't forget to #include queue.